# How to upload HTML file for site verification

Tags: file-uploads

I need to upload an html file to my site in order to verify my site for a Pinterest Business account. I am new to expressionengine and have no idea how or where to do this. Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with EE. Simply upload the verification file to your web server via FTP.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to upload a file to a web server, not about ExpressionEngine specifically

Answer (score 2):

1: create template with this html file name & content

2: use ftp to upload file